# Series with product of different power

Tags: power-series

I would like to know the analytical expression for the following series (if it exists):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} a^n b^{n^2}$

Does anybody have a clue on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

There have been questions on $\sum_{n \ge 0} x^{n^2}$ and similar [lacunary series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function) here. Such functions have singularities that are dense on the boundary of the circle of convergence, and can't be extended outside.

Comment: Thanks..but I don't see any relevant question that might help me.